# h2o warning message too old cluster

Tags: r, h2o

Hi i'm using `h2o` in R.

Just a couple of weeks ago i update `h2o` package to the latest version

```
 h2o.getVersion()
[1] "3.20.0.2"
```

But when i Initialize a new h2o session with `h2o.init` i recieve a warning message like that

```
In h2o.clusterInfo() : 
Your H2O cluster version is too old (3 months and 9 days)!
Please download and install the latest version from http://h2o.ai/download/
```

What should I do? When I installed h2o for the first time I don't recall having any file downloaded from h2o website.

Other info: OS Windows 10

```
 R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.0                         
year           2018                        
month          04                          
day            23                          
svn rev        74626                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
nickname       Joy in Playing
```

Comment: Did you update it again? Are you in the right directory?

Comment: R don't show any new update for h2o package

Comment: `install.packages("h2o",source="http://h2o.ai/download/")`?

Comment: Done. Same problem

Comment: Common steps, restart R, remove package and reinstall it, remove R and reinstall it.

Comment: No way I m going to remove R and reinstall it.

Comment: I don't think the warning is something to be too concerned about.  Version 3.20.02 came out on 2018-06-17, and the default behavior when launching h2o is to check if the version is more than 3 months old.  However, looking at CRAN, I see that h2o has been updated to 3.20.08 as of today 2018-09-25.  So that should get rid of the warning message for you.

Answer (score 6):

First remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.

```
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }
```

And then,  download packages that H2O depends on.

```
 pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
  if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
}
```

Download and install the H2O package for R.

```
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_R")))
```

Optionally initialize H2O and run a demo to see H2O at work.

```
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init()
demo(h2o.kmeans)
```

Or you can simply check the following link:

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#install-in-r

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I have tried this solution from the H2O.ai website but still receive the Error. I have found that uninstalling and reinstalling does Not clear the fact that H2O sees version Mismatches. Shouldn't there be an easier fix?

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. This should be marked as right answer.

Comment: It gave me a download error so I downloaded `h2o_3.32.1.6.tar.gz` (up to date at the time of writing) manually using `curl` and installed it by `install.packages("~/Downloads/h2o_3.32.1.6.tar.gz", repos=NULL)`. It shows no warnings now.

Comment: If a user doesn't have access to a CRAN mirror (common in corporate/university networks) they will end up without any version of h2o at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an warning message, so if you want, you can continue to use the H2O version you are using.

Please note it is expected that you would get this warning message. H2O wants you to know whether or not you are using an up-to-date version.

If you want the message to go away, all you need to do is update to the latest stable release: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html

Comment: If this is JUST a warning message and an alert THEN Do ppl feel that is incumbent on H2O.ai to provide a solution that solves this problem. I have tried their answer from their site and it Does Not Fix the error. I still get the error.